# Strange artifacts when animating rig

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, rigging, eevee-render-engine, artifacts

When rendering in Cycles these will pop up every so often on this rig. In Eevee it looks fine. I went through the vertex groups to make sure there's no doubling up or anything like that. Has anyone encountered something like this when animating their rigs?
[image: Cycles Render]
[image: Eevee Render]

Comment: I guess that's caused by the [motion blur](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/motion_blur.html). In any case, this should be reported to https://developer.blender.org/ to fix it.

Comment: But first check if there aren't any weird drivers. Because if a driver causes some weird location on subframes (which you can't see in the viewport or in EEVEE), then this motion blur is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Turning off motion blur did it. It's strange as I copied my key frames onto an earlier save of this rig and don't have the same blur problems.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured it out. Apparently autosmooth in rigs doesn't work very well when animated with motion blur. Turned off motion blur and fixed my geometry w/  holding loops and everything is fine.